# stringtotime from Unix timestamp

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am doing the following in my php script and I am not seeing the results I though I would:

```
$current_date_num = strtotime("now");
   echo $current_date_num ." BEFORE DATE HOUR<br/>";

$new_current = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($current_date_num));
   echo $new_current . " AFTER DATE<br/>";

$current_date_num = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($current_date_num) - 60 * 60 * 6);
   echo $current_date_num ." CURRENT<br/>";

$end_date = strtotime("+1 day");
$end_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$end_date);
   echo $end_date ." END DATE";
```

This is my output and Only the END DATE is showing what I would expect.

```
1322673564 BEFORE DATE HOUR
1969-12-31 07:00:00 AFTER DATE
1969-12-31 01:00:00 CURRENT
2011-12-01 12:19:24 END DATE
```

What I thought would happen is I get the Unix timestamp and then use strtotime and get the current time and then the current time minus 6 hours and finally the time 24 hours from now. Not sure how I am messing this up so bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying `strtotime()` two times too many. One time in line 4:

```
strtotime($current_date_num)
```

remove that, and the `strtotime()` call in line 7.

Comment: Now I see that. Thanks Let me update and see what happens then. +1

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) takes a human-readable time and parses it into a timestamp. As you already have a timestamp, the strptime calls are generating bogus data.

```
$current_date_num = strtotime("now");
echo $current_date_num ." BEFORE DATE HOUR<br/>";

$new_current = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $current_date_num);
echo $new_current . " AFTER DATE<br/>";

$current_date_num = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $current_date_num - 60 * 60 * 6);
echo $current_date_num ." CURRENT<br/>";

$end_date = strtotime("+1 day");
$end_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$end_date);
echo $end_date ." END DATE";
```

---

```
1322674409 BEFORE DATE HOUR
2011-11-30 06:33:29 AFTER DATE
2011-11-30 12:33:29 CURRENT
2011-12-01 06:33:29 END DATE
```